# Through vagrant running mvn command

Tags: maven, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I am working on writing vagrantfile for automation of local setup.
Through vagrant, i am creating docker image for my app and running it inside vm. Everything is under one command i.e. `vagrant up`
But one thing i have to do manual i.e. creating jar file for my app by using `mvn clean package`.

I am wondering is there any way to run mvn command from vagrantfile, so that when i issue `vagrant up`, it should build the JAR and do the rest of the work.

Comment: You could probably solve this by using [vagrant provisioning]( https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/). Perhaps the shell provisioner is suitable for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Patrick mentions, the shell provisioning is a good fit - I personally use for gradle but the same can be done for maven. Here is how I call my script

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "script/run-test.sh", privileged: false, run: 'always'
```

- `path` : is the path for my shell script from the project directory
- `privileged` : if not set, root will run the script, if maven is installed for your vagrant user, make sure to set it to false else you will see issue
- `run: 'always'` : this is my use-case (up to you to choose if it makes sense for you), the script will always run when I run `vagrant up`

the shell script will be something like

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "/home/vagrant/test" ];then 
    cd /home/vagrant/test && git pull
    cd /home/vagrant/test && maven compile
    cd /home/vagrant/test && maven deploy 
    .....

else
    git clone <your project> /home/vagrant/test
fi
```

This is an example, basically first time I create the instance it will clone a git repo - then it will pull from git latest files and run your maven command.

Again this is a simple example, use it for your own need